# How to get the number out of a HTML string without tags?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string inside the source of some website:

```
user_count: <b>5.122.512</b>
```

Is this possible to get the number out of this string, even if the tags around this number were different? I mean, `"user_count:"` part won't change, but the tags can be changed, to strong for example. Or the tags could be doubled, or whatever.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: What's the site? Use DOM ...

Comment: where is your peace of code which you have tried...? as we know you have to post questions when you have tried all the alternatives and failed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
user_count:\s*<.*?>(.*?)<.*?>
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iR4nR4/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you have to use JS to extract the content between the  tags `<b>5.122.512<b>` from the DOM.

If you can assign an ID to this you can probably use `document.getElementById('NAME_OF_YOUR_ID').innerHTML;` to extract the number between it. If you need to process this inside a PHP script, you would probably need to POST this back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to get the number out of the string. One would be just to strip the tags and run a regular expression.

```
$s = "user_count: <b>5.122.512</b>"
preg_match_all("@user_count: (.+)@", strip_tags($s), $matches);
print_r($matches)
```

$matches[1] should match the number.